# Redshift - ERROR: Invalid input syntax for type numeric

Tags: amazon-redshift

I use the aws - redshift now,but i got a Error like below when i run this query

```
<Query>
select
row_number() over(partition by nb.roadnumbercode
        order by sqrt(power((1.0*cast(ra.latitude as decimal(38,10)))-coalesce(nb.buildingcenterlatitude,0),2)
                +power((1.0*cast(ra.longitude as decimal(38,10)))-coalesce(nb.buildingcenterlongitude,0),2)
                )) rnum
from dmart.addresses ra join dmart.buildings nb on nb.roadnumbercode = ra.roadnamecode and nb.buildingcenterlatitude is not null and nb.buildingcenterlongitude is not null
limit 30;
```

[image]

Why this error cause ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are casting the empty string (“”) to a numeric which isn’t valid.  You need to handle the case where the string is empty, nut just NULL.